# What's going on with my bay leaf? Burnt looking leaves?

Tags: herbs, container-gardening

I purchased a bay leaf plant and noticed that some of the leaves are appearing burnt. I haven't repotted the plant yet. It's sitting in a nice sunny spot and I've been watering it.

[image]

I also noticed the top of the soil has solidified? Not sure if this is related or how this happened. I chipped it off... it definitely wasn't like that when I got it.

What should I do? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repot it into something better soil wise - not sure it needs a larger pot, you'll have to judge that by the amount of root inside when you turn it out, but use a decent potting compost. The second picture shows what looks like matted root material, but you'd have seen roots exposed beneath were it from the Bay, though its hard to imagine where else the roots might have come from.

When you've done that, move the plant to a sheltered spot, out of winds, where it gets dappled sunlight, or no sun between about 11-3 pm until it gets larger or at least puts on more healthy growth - these plants do like sun, but its possible this one is a little small to cope with hot sunlight. If its been in a windy spot, they really don't like that at all... It needs some time to recover, so keep it well watered in the meantime.

You could check beneath the leaves for signs of soft scale infestation, just to make sure there isn't anything else going on, but this looks like establishment failure (roots) and possible heat/drought issues.

Comment: My first thought was too much hot, dry wind. Bamboo's got that covered.